# How can I use for loop in jQuery hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use loops to iterate and apply hover with each element then remove class from another collection of elements. Tried each function but didn't work.

```js
$("#product").hover(function () {
    $(".z").removeClass("viz");
    $(".arrow1").css("transform", "rotate(180deg)")
}, function () {
    $(".z").addClass("viz");
    $(".arrow1").css("transform", "rotate(0deg)")
})
$("#company").hover(function () {
    $(".y").removeClass("viz");
    $(".arrow2").css("transform", "rotate(180deg)")
}, function () {
    $(".y").addClass("viz");
    $(".arrow2").css("transform", "rotate(0deg)")
})
$("#connect").hover(function () {
    $(".x").removeClass("viz");
    $(".arrow3").css("transform", "rotate(180deg)")
}, function () {
    $(".x").addClass("viz");
    $(".arrow3").css("transform", "rotate(0deg)")
})
```

Comment: This seems like an [XY question](http://xyproblem.info). You'll probably get better suggestions if you add some HTML so we can see what you're trying to accomplish. This looks like a very cumbersome approach which could be simplified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an array of the IDs of the elements you want to select and loop through them. like this:

```js
let list = ['product', 'company', 'connect']
list.forEach(element => {
  $("#"+element).hover(function () {
      $(".z").removeClass("viz");
      $(".arrow1").css("transform", "rotate(180deg)")
  }, function () {
      $(".z").addClass("viz");
      $(".arrow1").css("transform", "rotate(0deg)")
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

EDIT:
Using jquery selectors, for selecting list items of a ul with `id="menu"` is something like this:

```js
var items = $("ul#menu li");
for (let li of items) {
    $(li).hover(function () {
        // ...
    })
}
```

Comment: Hey BehRouz, this works, but is this possible with $("li")?

Comment: Yes, I'll revise the answer and add something with just jquery.